# Is it bad practice to end method names using the old asynchronous pattern with "Async"?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

In the recent [async/await pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), the recommendation is to end method names with "Async", such as "[GetAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)".

Now let's say I'm using the [old asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), i.e. the one with the Begin/End method pair and `IAsyncResult`. And I have a method that wraps a call to that method, such as:

```
public void SendAsync(byte[] data)
{
    this.stream.BeginWrite(...);
}
```

Also assume that the `EndWrite` method passed to `BeginWrite` is the same for all data, i.e. it would be a method in the same class.

In this case, is it wrong to name this method `SendAsync()` since it might be confused with the new async pattern?

Comment: I question the return type `void` here, you're creating fire and forget methods? How do you know when it has completed the write operation? Seems like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: Naming is probably subjective. But it is bad practice to create void async methods: http://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/c-beware-of-async-void-in-your-code/

Comment: To be consistent with .Net framework conventions use `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` naming.. Also your method doesn't adhere `APM` It should return `IAsyncResult`

Comment: It is just an example to illustrate the point. You could, for example, add an Action parameter that will run when the End... method is invoked.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the moniker Async on a method *means* that it has some kind of asynchronous notification mechanism when the operation it starts has completed. For me that means that in order for the method to be named Async, there **must** be some kind of callback mechanism. However, I would say *no*, don't name it like this. Either supply the standard IAsyncResult parameters and create BeginXXX and EndXXX, or use Task and call it Async, or find your own naming conventions for your different style. *But this is just an opinion!*

Comment: Actually, sorry for the confusion - in the particular scenario where I used this (where the stream is actually a NetworkStream), it *is* a fire-and-forget thing. There is separate code that is wired up to take care of data as it arrives on the network. In this very particular case there does not need to be a relationship between what was sent and the corresponding response because this is inherent in the protocol.

Comment: Please bear in mind that "fire and forget" also means "ignore all errors". Are you *sure* that's what you want for your network communications?

Comment: Errors in sending the actual data will result in an exception that the sender can handle. Errors in the protocol will be caught in the response when it comes back since the protocol provides for error conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As new frameworks/patterns/techniques are discovered/created/implemented, new rules or advises appear.

The naming conventions are just a way to create a standard in order to make code more unified between developers; that doesn't mean you can't use the one you like the most or is more useful to you (unless you are ina  company that enforces conventions).

From my POV, I wouldn't adopt the new convention in what is now your legacy code.

Also, **I always prefer to use a naming convention similar to the framework I'm using so that it will be easier to any other developer working with me.**

Check this (kind of old but still pretty good):
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 just for the bold sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the APM (Asynchronous Pattern Module) and name my methods with BeginXXX and EndXXX.

Also, make sure your methods implement the pattern properly by returning an IAsyncResult and not void as you are returning from this method.

APM: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: As I said in the assumption, there is a method EndWrite() which already uses IAsyncResult - it is just not visible from the code that will use this class/method.